# sweetalert: how pass argument to callback

Tags: javascript, callback

I am using javascript alert library [sweetalert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)

My code is:

```
function foo(id) {
    swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
      closeOnConfirm: false
    },
    function(){
      swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
    });
}
```

How can I pass `id` from `foo()` function to callback function in swal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function(id){
  alert(MyId);
  swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
});
```

This will not work, because in this case **id** is the option **isConfirm** for your confirmation dialog - see [SweetAlert Documentation](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/).

This will work - no need for an additional variable:

```
function foo(id) {
  swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
    closeOnConfirm: false
  },
  function(isConfirm){
    alert(isConfirm);
    alert(id);
    swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
  }); 
} 
foo(10);
```

here the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/60bLyy2k/

Answer (score 3):

just put your parameter in local variable they are accessible in inner function or in clousers

```
function foo(id) {
    var MyId = id;
    swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
      closeOnConfirm: false
    },
    function(){
        alert(MyId);
      swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
    });
}

foo(10);
```

here the fiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/](https://jsfiddle.net/9gc0gcrq/)

Comment: why are are passing it in `function(id){` ?? you can directly access `MyId`

Comment: in inner function(id){ no need of id here so i removed that and also corrected url of fiddle

Comment: Still seems like master of spaghetti code