# How to make code execution wait until a value is inputted in Sweetalert prompt?

Tags: javascript, alert, prompt

I want to code execution wait until a value is inputted in sweet alert prompt. Basically, I want a blocking behaviour from sweet alert prompt same as the basic js prompt.

```
let value= Swal.fire({
title: "An input!",
text: "Write something interesting:",
input: 'text',
showCancelButton: true
```

})

This is the sweet alert prompt code which stores the value in 'value'. Right now, the operation is async. I want further code execution to wait until I don't get the value.

If there is any other library other than sweet alert than can perform the intended behaviour, I am interested in that. 
All I want is a stylized prompt with a blocking behaviour.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218861/sweetalert-how-pass-argument-to-callback

Answer (score 0):

I believe sweet alert can handle promises. So when you you execute your code, you can do

```
value.then( (foo) => {
// your code goes here after the input is received
})
```

Or if you didn't want to store it in a variable and just run the raw sweet alert code:

```
Swal.fire({
title: "An input!",
text: "Write something interesting:",
input: 'text',
showCancelButton: true        
})
.then((foo) => {
// your code goes here after the input is received
});
```

In this case foo is going to be what the user provided as input

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. But still, the rest of the code is getting executed completely ignoring sweet alert prompt.

Comment: What is the rest of your code? Whatever you want to come after the prompt will have to be executed within the promise. Remember, you can run functions etc inside that promise

Comment: Got it. I think I found the mistake. Thanks for clearing the things out. I appreciate it.